# jQuery UI draggable handler position offset when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

There seems to be a lot of discussion on web about this issue, but non of the solutions helped me. The problem is that on FF and IE I have my draggable helper clone position offset with a number of page scrolled pixels. I tried "overflow:auto" on body, I also  checked if any of parents have position: relative. It seems fine to me. Maybe I just need a pair of fresh eyes to look at my code. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zEb7y/3/.

It's important that you minimize page so that you have a scroll on the "Result" section. First try to drag a container with a page scrolled to the top and then scroll a bit down and you will see the offset.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="productView" class="tiles">

        <div class="productList" id="productList">

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="A1" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="A2" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="A3" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="product" data-regnumber="LO12NWU">
                <a id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ContentPlaceHolderContent_ListViewVehicles_ctrl0_Hyperlink_VehicleDetails" href="#">

                    <div class="productImage">

                        <div class="shortListOverlay">
                            <div class="buttonHolder add">
                                <span>Drag to Shortlist</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="productDetails" style="height: 105px;">

                    </div>


                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="shortList">
        <div class="inner">
            <header>
                <h3>Shortlist</h3>
                <span class="productCount">0</span>
                <a href="#" class="viewAll">View all</a>
                <a href="#" class="visibilityHandler">X</a>
            </header>
            <div class="thumbnailContainer">
                <a href="#" class="prev thumbNav"><</a>
                <div class="productContainer">
                    <div class="products"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="next thumbNav">></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.products {
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .products {
      padding: 80px 10px 0 0;
      margin-left: 10px; } }
  .products .productView {
    overflow: hidden; }
    .products .productView .noResults {
      padding: 40px 0;
      text-align: center; }
  .products .title {
    margin: 0 0 20px; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
      .products .title {
        text-align: right;
        margin: 10px 0 10px; } }
  .products .subTitle {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif;
    font-size: 16px; }
  .products .productList {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%; }
  .products .product {
    width: 24.9%;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 2000px) {
      .products .product {
        width: 20%; } }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
      .products .product {
        width: 25%; } }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
      .products .product {
        width: 33%; } }
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .products .product {
        width: 50%; } }
    .products .product .finance.loading {
      background: white url(/Images/Common/Interface/loader_inline_grey.gif) no-repeat center center;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 10px; }
    .products .product .finance.loading * {
      display: none; }
    .products .product a {
      display: block;
      color: #333333;
      background: #ccc;
      margin-right: 5px;
      -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
      transition: all 250ms ease-in-out; }
      .products .product a .productImage {
        position: relative; }
        .products .product a .productImage img {
          max-width: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
          border: 0; }
        .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay {
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0 auto;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          cursor: pointer; }
          .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay span {
            color: #fff; }
          .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay .buttonHolder {
            width: 90%;
            padding: 5px 5%;
            background: #000;
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
            /* IE 8 */
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            /* IE 5-7 */
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 250ms ease-in-out; }
            @media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
              .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay .buttonHolder {
                font-size: 10px; } }
            @media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
              .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay .buttonHolder {
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
                /* IE 8 */
                filter: alpha(opacity=80);
                /* IE 5-7 */
                opacity: 0.8; }
                .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay .buttonHolder .icon {
                  visibility: visible; } }
            .products .product a .productImage .shortListOverlay .buttonHolder.remove {
              display: none;
              -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
              /* IE 8 */
              filter: alpha(opacity=80);
              /* IE 5-7 */
              opacity: 0.8; }
      .products .product a .productDetails {
        padding: 5px;
        overflow: hidden; }
        .products .product a .productDetails h1 {
          font: bold 16px "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
          margin: 0; }
          .products .product a .productDetails h1 .makeModel {
            display: block; }
          .products .product a .productDetails h1 .derivative {
            color: #555;
            font-size: 90%; }
          @media screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
            .products .product a .productDetails h1 {
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: 14px; } }
          @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            .products .product a .productDetails h1 {
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: 12px; } }
        .products .product a .productDetails p {
          margin: 0;
          font: normal 14px "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; }
          @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            .products .product a .productDetails p {
              font-size: 12px; } }
        .products .product a .productDetails h3 {
          margin: 0 5px 0 0;
          float: left;
          font: bold 14px "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; }
          @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            .products .product a .productDetails h3 {
              font-size: 12px;
              margin: 0 3px 0 0; } }
        .products .product a .productDetails h4 {
          margin: 0;
          font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; }
          @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            .products .product a .productDetails h4 {
              font-size: 12px; } }
      .products .product a:hover {
        background: #29a6ee;
        color: #fff; }
        .products .product a:hover h3 {
          color: #fff; }
        .products .product a:hover .productDetails h1 .derivative {
          color: #fff; }
        .products .product a:hover .shortListOverlay .add {
          -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
          /* IE 8 */
          filter: alpha(opacity=80);
          /* IE 5-7 */
          opacity: 0.8; }
      .products .product a .extendedFeatures {
        display: none; }
      @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        .products .product a {
          font-size: 12px; } }

.shortList {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  background: whitesmoke; }
  .shortList .inner header {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background: black;
    overflow: hidden; }
    .shortList .inner header h3 {
      margin: 0 20px 0 0;
      font-weight: bold;
      dispaly: inline-block;
      color: white;
      float: left; }
    .shortList .inner header .productCount {
      color: white;
      padding: 3px 10px;
      margin: 0 20px 0 0;
      float: left;
      background: #262626; }
    .shortList .inner header .viewAll {
      color: white;
      padding: 3px 5px;
      float: left;
      display: none; }
    .shortList .inner header .visibilityHandler {
      width: 16px;
      height: 26px;
      float: right;
      display: none;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      background: url(/Images/Common/Icons/icon_gallery_close.png) no-repeat center center; }
  .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 35px;
    overflow: hidden; }
    .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .thumbNav {
      width: 25px;
      display: block;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      margin-top: -27px;
      padding: 18px 0 17px;
      position: absolute; }
      .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .thumbNav.prev {
        top: 50%;
        left: 5px;
        background: gray url(/Images/Common/Icons/icon_gallery_arrow_left.png) no-repeat center center; }
      .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .thumbNav.next {
        top: 50%;
        right: 5px;
        background: gray url(/Images/Common/Icons/icon_gallery_arrow_right.png) no-repeat center center; }
    .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative; }
      .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer.ui-state-default {
        border: none; }
      .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products {
        height: 54px;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 0; }
        .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product {
          width: 145px;
          margin: 0 5px 0 0;
          float: left; }
          .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product a {
            margin: 0;
            cursor: pointer; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product a:hover .productDetails h1 {
              color: white; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product a:hover .productDetails p {
              color: white; }
          .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productImage {
            width: 65px;
            float: left; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productImage img {
              border: 0 none;
              display: block;
              max-width: 100%;
              width: 100%; }
          .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails {
            height: 43px;
            padding: 3px 5px;
            margin-left: 65px; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails h1 {
              font-size: 12px;
              font-weight: bold;
              line-height: 14px;
              color: black;
              margin: 0 0 3px 0; }
              .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails h1 .derivative {
                display: none; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails p {
              display: none; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails .price {
              font-size: 12px; }
              @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
                .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails .price {
                  font-size: 10px; } }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails .finance {
              display: none; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .productDetails h4 {
              display: none; }
          .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .extendedFeatures {
            display: none; }
          .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .controls {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 2px; }
            .shortList .inner .thumbnailContainer .productContainer .products .product .controls .button {
              font-size: 12px;
              color: white;
              padding: 5px 7px;
              border: none;
              margin-top: 5px;
              background: #cd3939; }
```

**JS:**

```
var thisObj = this,
    shortList = jQuery('.shortList'),
    productList = jQuery('.productList'),
    product = productList.find('.product'),
    shortListOverlay = product.find('.shortListOverlay'),
    productContainer = shortList.find('.productContainer'),
    shortlistedProducts = productContainer.find('.products'),
    productArray = [],
    viewAll = shortList.find('header').find('.viewAll'),
    visibilityHandler = shortList.find('header').find('.visibilityHandler'),
    visibilityState = {},
    currentThumb = 0,
    productCount = shortList.find('.productCount'),
    controls = productContainer.prev().add(productContainer.next()),
    productsInLine = 0;

product.draggable({
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: 'clone',
    addClasses: false,
    scroll: false
});

productContainer.droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    activate: function (event, ui) {

        shortList
        .animate({
            'bottom': '0'
        }, 200, function () {
            visibilityHandler.fadeIn(200);
        });

        ui.helper.find('.productDetails').removeAttr('style');
    },
    deactivate: function (event, ui) {
        var target = jQuery(this).find('.products');

        if (!target.children('.product').length) {
            shortList
            .animate({
                'bottom': '-' + shortList.outerHeight()
            });

        }
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var target = jQuery(this).find('.products'),
            targetLength = target.children('.product').length;

        shortList.addClass('visible');

        ui.draggable.draggable("disable");
    }
});
```